# How to get a string from url using preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to extract id from an url using php preg_match..

For eg: `$string = 'http://www.mysite.com/profile.php?id=1111';` I need output as `'1111'`

using preg_match.

I tried this :

```
if(preg_match('/(?:https?):\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/profile\.php\?id\=[0-9]/', $string, $match) > 0){

    $id =  $match[1];
}
```

But am getting output as '`profile.php`'

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Why don't you just take it w/ `parse_url`?

Comment: You have mistake in regex, id\=[0-9] should be written as id=([0-9]+)

Comment: @DainisAbols : No i want to check the url name, if its correct only i need the id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is only one parameter in the url you can use explode function to do that easily, like

```
$string = 'http://www.mysite.com/profile.php?id=1111';
$ex=explode('=',$string);
$id=$ex[1];
```

You may also use parse_url function of php.

Hope this help,

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$url_component = parse_url($string);
parse_str($url_component['query'], $output);
echo $output['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/(?:https?):\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/profile\.php\?id\=([0-9]+)/';
```

This should work fine!
But do this with [parse_url](https://www.php.net/parse_url)